# How to print process's outputs while `make`?

Tags: makefile, homebrew, formula

How to print **`cargo build`'s process** while `make` in `brew install`?

### Makefile

```
CARGO=RUSTFLAGS='-F warnings' cargo

...

release:
  $(CARGO) build --all  --release
...
```

### Formula

```rb
def install 
  # system command
  system "make release"

  # copy files
  libexec.install Dir["*"] 

  # exec links
  bin.install_symlink "#{libexec}/target/install/bin"  
end
```

### Outputs

```
...
==> make release
# *** need outputs here ***
```

Comment: Which process do you mean?

Comment: `cargo build` inside `make` while `brew install`....

Comment: Did you the verbose flag: `brew install -v cita` ?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni yes...I'm trying to fix it up.

Comment: The command `make release` should print the output from `cargo`. So it appears that the problem is getting cita to print the output of its actions (e.g. `system "./env.sh make release"`). I don't know cita, so I can't answer that, but I suggest you simplify this problem to remove Make from it entirely.

Comment: thank you @Beta, `cargo run` has print itself, but doesn't work while it nesting into `make`, I should ask this.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Hey body, I realized, what you suggested exactly now... I misunderstood your meaning, compiling locally might not a good choice, I decided to download compiled last night, but I'll try it soon! thx!

Comment: Ah! Then I suggest you remove the cita layer. And also please tell us more about what `cargo` is and, if possible, how we can run it.